# How to reset AWS session token automatically while script is running

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudtrail

I have a script that takes over 4 hours long. My session can only run up until 4 hours before the script gives me the following error:

An error occurred (ExpiredTokenException) when calling the LookupEvents operation: The security token included in the request is expired

Is there any way to have the script automatically get new credentials?

I am using aws-azure-login to update my .aws/credentials file

I don't have a solution at this time.

Comment: We need to see the script if you want help debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that library has an `--no-prompt` flag that will keep you logged in.

https://github.com/aws-azure-login/aws-azure-login#staying-logged-in-skip-usernamepassword-for-future-logins